# How do I send a message to a routee from a router?

Tags: akka

I am trying to work with RoundRobinRoutingLogic in Akka 2.4 to work through Jonas Boner's Pi calculation example. The docs only show how to create a router and then use route to send a message back to the sender. This is just resulting in a long list of deadletters.

```
class Master(numOfWorkers: Int, numOfMessages: Int, numOfElements: Int,  listener: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  var pi: Double = _
  var numOfResults: Int = _
  val start: Long = System.currentTimeMillis

  val workerRouter = {
    val routees = Vector.fill(5) {
      val r = context.actorOf(Props[Worker])
      context watch r
      ActorRefRoutee(r)
    }
    Router(RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees)
  }

    def receive = {
        case Calculate => for (i <- 0 until numOfMessages) workerRouter.route(Work(i * numOfElements, numOfElements), sender())
        case Result(value) =>
          pi += value
          numOfResults += 1
          if (numOfResults == numOfMessages) {
            listener ! PiApproximation(pi, duration = (System.currentTimeMillis - start).millis)
            context.stop(self)
    }
  }
}
```

I have a Worker actor defined that is getting created and added to the routees of the workerRouter. For the Calculate case, how can I send a Work message to the Worker that would be chosen next by the RoundRobinRoutingLogic?

Comment: Could you elaborate?  wokerRouter.route does what you're asking for.  Are you trying to get the ActorRef of the next Actor queued up by workerRouter?

Comment: Yeah I think that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @redeagle47 Do you have the complete code somewhere? It would really help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing `sender()` to the underlying worker `ActorRef` as the destination for Results, instead of sending the ref to Master.  If you modify the following line it should fix the problem you are seeing:

```
//note the "self" instead of "sender()"
case Calculate => for (i <- 0 until numOfMessages) workerRouter.route(Work(i * numOfElements, numOfElements), self)
```

Also, I would "break up" your code a bit as follows:

```
def sendWork(i : Int) = 
  workerRouter.route(Work(i * numOfElements, numOfElements), self)

def receive = {
  case Calculate => (1 until numOfMessages) foreach sendWork

  ...
}
```

Comment: ah, it was the self reference that I wasn't seeing. The example in the docs kept using sender() which I knew wasn't right, but I couldn't see what I should use instead. I thought I would have to access the routees directly, but didn't understand how. This makes a lot more sense. Also, thanks for the advice about refactoring. I was just running through the example, so I hadn't really looked at that yet.